# Using Vue and axios post to json file problem

Tags: json, vue.js, localhost, http-status-code-404, axios

I got problem with axis posting to local .json file. It gives me an error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/todolist.json 404 (Not Found)

TodoListEditor.vue?b9d6:110 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

I tried many address schemes but everything ends the same. When I pass exact same address into *axios.get()* - it returns proper data and reads the file.
Here's my part of code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/todolist.json',
        this.todolist,{
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        }
      }).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you want to POST to that address? It very likely that POST is not supported. The returned error code should be "405 Method Not Allowed", but maybe that's a slip up.

Comment: This is not how you should edit JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types of HTTP requests GET and POST have their own roles. GET is a request to retrieve information, POST is a request to write data, and the server acts differently for each method. The above error indicates that the server is unable to process the request for POST requests.

Sending a get request from the URL above seems to work well because it means bringing in the todolist.json file, and sending a post request to a specific file is inappropriate.